# JDBC - phpMyAdmin MySQL Can't login to database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm hosting a web application through **OpenShift**. I added a MySQL database and created it with phpMyAdmin. Now, I think my server name is the name it shows on the phpMyAdmin page (`127.01.201.302` for example). Now, I created a user 'localhostOnly' with the same password, I set the host to 'localhost' and priviliges to the insert, select update and delete.

But when i try to connect to it with the:

`jdbc:mysql://127.01.201.302:3306/DB_NAME` and using those login credentials, it gives this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'localhostOnly'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at database.OpeningsTijdenDAO.selectTijden(OpeningsTijdenDAO.java:15)
at database.OTService.getTijden(OTService.java:13)
at servlets.GetTijdenServlet.doPost(GetTijdenServlet.java:17)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**NOTE: I am absolutely sure the login credentials are correct. I do not have XAMMP or something installed.**

Answer (score 0):

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

By having a look at the last line of the entire error-trace. I can assume that your program failed to locate your server by given URL. I think you might be missing port number for your MySQL server. If you haven't changed your port number, then it's most likely 3307 by default. Change your Database Source URL from

```
jdbc:mysql://127.01.201.302/DB_NAME
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://127.01.201.302:3307/DB_NAME
```

Comment: Excuse me, my bad. I do have the port in the URL, :3306 though, with :3307 I get a communicating link failure and connecting refused